# get variable in catch clause

Tags: exception, haskell, catch-block, stm

Hello I need to write function than will send and receive messages over tcp and auto reconnect if connection is broken. Messages is taken from STM Channel

```
f ch a b = 
    h <- connectTo a b
    forever $ do
        c <- atomically $ readTChan ch
        {- do smth with c -}
    `catch` (const $ f ch a b)
```

My problem is that if connection is broken I'll lost 'c' that I've read from channel.
So in `catch` clause I want to no something like unGetTChan but in this code 'c' 
is not in catch. Can you advise ''haskellic'' way to do such a thing?

### update after  FUZxxl's message

After FUZxxl's comment I've rewritten function into next form

```
fun ch a b = do
h <- connectTo a b
forever $ do
    c <- atomically $ readTChan chan
    do   
        {- do smth with c -}
        `catch` (const $ do
            atomically $ unGetTChan chan c
            fun chan con
            )
```

now it works for me.
thanks

Comment: I think you have a missleading design. Try to separate to catch-clause to the only action that may throw an exception. For instance, if reading `c` can't cause an exception, why not separate the `catch`-clauses?

Comment: is `chan` the `ch` argument to `fun`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a missleading design. Try to separate to catch-clause to the only action that may throw an exception. For instance, if reading c can't cause an exception, why not separate the catch-clauses?